# Max Amount of Loops

Tags: php, loops

i have loops script like this

```
for($i=0; $i < count($json); $i++) { 

}
```

for example, amount of $json is "12" or anything more than 10, but i want the max of that loops is 10, but, if i use this script

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++) {

}
```

the result will be 10, but what if the $json amount I got is less than 10? means there will be NULL results, is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `min()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php)

```
$count = min (count($json), 10);
for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { 

}
```

It's best to do the min outside the `for` so that it's only done once.

Answer (score 1):

```
$count=count($json);
if($count > 10){
$count = 10;
}
for ($x = 0; $x < $count; $x++) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use array_slice to grab the first 10 of the array and foreach them.
This way you will always just loop 10 times at the most.

```
$json =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
//$json =[1,2,3,4,5,6]; //uncomment if you want to test with smaller array

$arr = array_slice($json, 0,10);

Foreach($arr as $val){
    Echo $val ."\n";
}
```

This can also be written like this:

```
Foreach(array_slice($json, 0,10) as $val){
    Echo $val ."\n";
}
```

But I spelled it out just to make it clear.

You can try the code here: https://3v4l.org/7pV3X